# Hosting .NET 5 ASP.NET app on Window 10 Pro IIS

Tags: iis, .net-core

I have a simple, functional .NET 5.0 console app that I'm trying to host (for testing) on my local Windows 10 Pro development machine.

I have the Application Pool setup as "No Managed Code" and "Integrated".
I have a website created that points to the folder that I've published my app to.

My app uses NLog and when I hit the app's URL, I do see that NLog is logging things correctly.

Yet my app isn't functioning and when I check the Windows Application Event Log I see:

```
Source: IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Event ID: 1007
Message: Application '/LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Cabinet\Learning\EssApiGateway\Mobile.ApiGatewayPublished\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
Managed server didn't initialize after 120000 ms.
File Version: 15.0.21076.5. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler.
```

I have installed the .NET Core Hosting Bundle from here and restarted IIS:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.5-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Can I not host a .NET 5 ASP.NET console app on Windows 10 Pro IIS?

Thanks, Brent

Comment: Is it possible that this is a problem with your project. I suggest you deploy a core template project first

Comment: Ding, my project was created from a template and it is a very basic project. It is an API Gateway. All I have done is install the Ocelot 17.0 package and configured it. When I run my project from within VS.NET, it runs and functions correctly - it passes incoming requests to the routes I've setup in the ocelot config file, to another project that contains the actual api. This seems like an issue with the IIS AspNetCoreModule and Windows 10 IIS, since that is what is throwing the error when trying to load coreclr.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this, sort of.

In Program.cs, I am creating a new WebHostBuilder() and I was calling .UseKestrel().
When I changed that to UseIIS(), my gateway project runs and functions correctly when hosted by IIS.

But then when I run my project in VS.NET by using the project's launch profile (how I typically run these type of projects), it fails with this error:

'No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer' has been registered.'

But then if I run my project in VS.NET with the IIS Express launch profile, it again runs
and functions fine.

So I need to educate myself about the components involved so I better understand...